# Irreducible and separable polynomial

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over $F[X]$, with $char(F)=p$ prime number. We know that $ \exists t \in \mathbb{N} | f(x)=g((x^p)^t)$. We shall prove that $g(x)$ is irreducible and separable.

I know a Proposition which states that if $f(x)$ is irreducible it is equivalent to be in the form $f(x)=h(x^p)$ with $char(F)=p\ne 0$ and have multiple roots. But I can't figure out how to fruitfully apply it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://books.google.dk/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=Let%20F%20have%20prime%20characteristic%20p%20and%20let%20f%20%E2%88%88%20F%20%5Bx%5D%20be%20irreducible.%20Then%20f%28x%29%20=%20g%28xpe%29%20for%20some%20integer%20e%20%E2%89%A5%200%20and%20some%20irreducible,%20separable%20polynomial%20g%20%E2%88%88%20F%5Bx%5D.&source=bl&ots=Y-V3dsc-nI&sig=JA1tjewO-ZzyNM0H0Z1wpkK4uAo&hl=da&sa=X&ei=_tGOUM2XK8_V4QTzmYC4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Let%20F%20have%20prime%20characteristic%20p%20and%20let%20f%20%E2%88%88%20F%20%5Bx%5D%20be%20irreducible.%20Then%20f%28x%29%20=%20g%28xpe%29%20for%20some%20integer%20e%20%E2%89%A5%200%20and%20some%20irreducible,%20separable%20polynomial%20g%20%E2%88%88%20F%5Bx%5D.&f=false) link: this is well-known theorem in Galois/Field Theory. See proposition 2.5 and above.

Comment: Thank you! Also for the book, it will definitely help!